# get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given

Tags: php

I got this error in several places of code, when I tried to deploy Symfony 2.8 project on new local machine:

```
"Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given"
```

Haven't find such case on stackoverflow and spent some time to figure out the reason.

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) states: `Note: Explicitly passing NULL as the object is no longer allowed as of PHP 7.2.0. The parameter is still optional and calling get_class() without a parameter from inside a class will work, but passing NULL now emits an E_WARNING notice.`

Comment: @Script47 read the answer given by the OP

Comment: fuel php fix: elseif (is_object($value) && $value instanceof \Iterator or get_class($value) == 'stdClass')

Answer (score 9):

As stated elsewhere on this question, in PHP 7.2 [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) manual states:

> Note: Explicitly passing NULL as the object is no longer allowed as of PHP 7.2.0. The parameter is still optional and calling get_class() without a parameter from inside a class will work, but passing NULL now emits an E_WARNING notice.

As you found with [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49751992/3536236).

***However*** you stated:

> So downgrading php version to 7.1 solved the problem.

Downgrading PHP is not usually the best or long term way to solve problems*; instead you need to wrap the `get_class` in a *checker* function such as [`is_object`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php), or inversely, `is_null`:

```
$baz = new class();
$className = false; // catch all if $baz is not an object
if(is_object($baz)){
    $className = get_class($baz);
}
```

- As stated by [Nicco Hasse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751991/get-class-expects-parameter-1-to-be-object-null-given/49752124#comment86519281_49752124)
  *If this problem occurs within Symfony code, just changing the Symfony code is not a good idea. And as upgrading Symfony is not an option, as stated in the OPs answer, staying on 7.1 seems to be the best solution*

I would say that while it may be fiddly to "fix" Symphony code, I would suggest adding the qualifier `is_object` to the Symphony code and then updating to the latest Symphony version when it comes out (which I hope would fix this issue).

Comment: If this problem occurs within Symfony code, just changing the Symfony code is not a good idea. And as upgrading Symfony is not an option, as stated in the OPs answer, staying on 7.1 seems to be the best solution

Comment: @NicoHaase that is a good point. I have updated my answer.  I would aso say I would say that it may be fiddly to "fix" Symphony code, but I would suggest adding the qualifier `is_object` to the Symphony code and then updating to the latest Symphony version when it comes out (which I hope would fix this issue).

Answer (score 4):

The [latest versions of Symfony 2.7 and 2.8 should be fully compatible with PHP7.2](https://symfony.com/blog/get-ready-for-php-7-2), however I was still getting this error. Upgrading sonata-project/user-bundle from 3.3 to 3.6 resolved that issue.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the difference of PHP versions. This new warning was implemented in PHP 7.2 - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/get_class_disallow_null_parameter

So downgrading php version on my local machine to 7.1 (like it is on production server) solved the problem.

I believe that upgrading vendors might solve it too, but in my case this way is not welcome by customer.

Answer (score 0):

This exact error has occurred with me for different reason than above. I am using Laravel version 8 and php 7.4 and it happened because I was casting a model property (unsignedSmallInteger) in particular to number instead of integer.

In short, **casting to wrong type might cause this issue**.