# get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given (Yajra Datatable)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, yajra-datatable

When I am retrieving data using yajra datatable I am getting an error like below. Same code for other things it's working.  I don't know what is wrong with the below code. Please help me.

```
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\usermanagement\vendor\yajra\laravel-datatables-oracle\src\DataTables.php"
line: 63
message: "get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given"
```

controller

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $data = Lead::find($request->leadid)->notes;

        return Datatables::of($data)
        ->addColumn('actions','lead.notebutton')
        ->rawColumns(['actions'])
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->make(true);


    }
```

thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get\_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751991/get-class-expects-parameter-1-to-be-object-null-given)

Comment: I have not upgraded any version and other things are working fine if it is null also

Comment: What is on line 63 of the file ```C:\xampp\htdocs\usermanagement\vendor\yajra\laravel-datatables-oracle\src\DataTables.php``` ?

What is the content of ```Lead::find($request->leadid)->notes``` that you are passing into the ```of()``` method?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper thanks for your response. Now I got the point the elequent relation is returning null instead of empty object. It is problem in relationship